# Unable to update database using asynchronous method

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, asynchronous

I am trying to update some values to my database using async task but I get this error:

> Values not inserted. Error: SQL logic error or missing database

Here is the code I use to update the db:

```
- (void)persistResponseData:(NSDictionary *)data database:(DataBaseHandler *)database completion:(void (^)(NSError *error))completion {

    NSDictionary *contentData = [data objectForKey:@"contentdata"];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{


        // Process Contents
        NSArray *contents = [contentData objectForKey:@"contents"];
        if (contents != nil) {
            [self storeData:contents inTable:@"contents" database:database withCustomIdentifier:nil];
        }

    });

    }
```

The error occurs on this line of code with error code EXC_BAD_ACCESS:

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)==SQLITE_OK)
```

which is called when I try to confirm if a record exists or not, inside the storeData function.

If I remove the asynchronous part

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
```

then the code runs without any problem and the database gets updated. 
Any idea how to resolve this ?

Comment: Looks like SQLite doesn’t like you accessing the DB from multiple threads?

Comment: You may need to set a flag to enable this https://sqlite.org/threadsafe.html